# How should I split a string with no spaces in vim script?

Tags: vimrc, split

How should I split a string with no spaces in vim script?
All the options which I see are to split a string with spaces.
I even tried split(string_name) without a delimiter , but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\zs` as delimiter to split string into individual characters:

```
:echo split("Hello", '\zs')
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Comment: how do you do with selected text?